# Deciding whether a user's new score is their best score achieved on a specific activity

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to create a database where the user will complete a series of activities, and their score from each activity will be stored in an 'ActivityLog' table, here is the current format:

[image: DB Table Format]

My actual question is when I enter a new record into this table, how would I check whether their score is their best score for that specific activity? I will need to ensure that I am checking the high score for this correct activity, as well as the correct user.

The desired output will look something similar to this (user_id and activity_id will not be null):

[image: Desired DB Format]

The `improvement` column is equal to true when the user's score is greater than their highest score for that specific game, thus creating a new improvement. The logic here must only compare the highest score that this specific *user* has achieved on this specific *activity*. I am unsure whether the best approach would be using a trigger to automatically check this upon a database insert?

The reason I am storing these improvements is because I am hoping to retrieve the amount of records where the improvement is equal to true, and visualize these in a graph.

Here is the trigger I've got so far:

```
 /* Improvements Trigger */
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkImprovement
AFTER INSERT
ON ActivityLog
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE hs int;

    SELECT hs = MAX(score) WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND activity_name = NEW.activity_name;

    IF(NEW.score > hs)
       UPDATE ActivityLog
       SET improvement = 1
       WHERE log_id = NEW.log_id
    ELSE
       UPDATE ActivityLog
       SET improvement = 0
       WHERE log_id = NEW.log_id
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

However this code is not currently working and provides me with an error:

'#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND activity_name = NEW.activity_name;'

I'm sure there's a lot to work on here, but I would appreciate a brief explanation of how to approach this!

Comment: Use `MAX(score)` and `GROUP BY user_id, activity_played`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, how would I automatically store it in the 'improvement' column upon the entry of a new record?

Comment: Subtract the new score from this to calculate the improvement.

Comment: The 'improvement' column is is in boolean format, so how would I use your suggested method of checking, and automatically set the improvement to true or false when a new record is entered. Would I use a trigger in this scenario @Barmar?

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was the amount of improvement. Use `IF(NEW.score > MAX(score), 1, 0)`

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense, thanks @Barmar. Am I correct in thinking I would use this in an 'AFTER Insert' trigger?

Comment: yeah, that sounds right. Try implementing, if you can't get it working post what you tried

Comment: Also MAX(score) retrieves all scores regardless of user, I am assuming I would use 'WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id'? Or would it be something to do wit your suggested 'group by' method?

Comment: WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND activity = NEW.activity

Comment: Okay so I have tried your suggestion @Barmar with the following code: `/* Improvements Trigger */
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkImprovement
AFTER INSERT
ON ActivityLog
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE hs int;
 
 SELECT hs = MAX(score) WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND activity_name = NEW.activity_name;
 
 IF(NEW.score > hs)
       UPDATE ActivityLog
       SET improvement = 1
       WHERE log_id = NEW.log_id
 ELSE
       UPDATE ActivityLog
       SET improvement = 0
       WHERE log_id = NEW.log_id
END //
DELIMITER ;`. This gives me an error near `WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id`.

Comment: don't put code in comments, edit the question so it's readable.

Comment: Added the code to the question.

Comment: Is it working? If not, explain what the problem is.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment this code gives me an error. phpmyadmin is giving the usual unhelpful error message of 'an error near WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors.

You need to use `SET` to assign the result of a query to a variable (or you can use `SELECT ... INTO variable`).

You need `THEN` in the `IF` statement, and you need `;` at the end of each statement in the `IF/THEN/ELSE/` block. But you don't really need `IF`, since the value of a condition is either `1` or `0` depending on whether it's true or false.

You're missing the `FROM` clause in the query that gets `MAX(score)`. I've used `userTable` below as a placeholder.

You're updating ALL rows for all users in with the same activity, since you don't have `user_id` in the `WHERE` clauses, nor does it specify a particular log row for the user. I think what you really want to do is set the `improvement` column in the new row that's being inserted, not update existing rows. So you should use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that sets `NEW.improvement`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkImprovement
BEFORE INSERT ON ActivityLog
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.improvement = 
        NEW.score > (
            SELECT MAX(score) 
            FROM ActivityLog
            WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND activity_name = NEW.activity_name);
//
DELIMITER ;
```

You could also combine all this into a single query:

```
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE ActivityLog SET improvement = (SELECT MAX(score)
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I have been looking for, thank you! As you can tell, SQL is pretty new to me, but it certainly seems like an interesting language.